# Text File Reading Issue in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, file-handling

I have designed a linklist based BookStore in which book's attributes will be stored in a node & so on. Plus at the end of program, I have to save all database into text file *(I tried binary reading but damn I got me killed & couldn't do it)* & then reload all info, of each book one by one & store it in nodes & re-make the LinkList.
Now saving is done & no issue at all. But Im having issues in reading from text file.

**Saving structure in file is:::**

BookID(int) - BookName(string) - Author(string) - BookType(string) - Copies(long) - Price(long) - '\n' (to go to next line)

**EXAMPLE:**
1 ObjectOrientedParadigm R.Lafore Coding 5 900 
2 ObjectOrientedParadigm R.Lafore Coding 5 900
and so on......

Here is the saving function.

```
bool BookStoreDataBase<mytype>::save_all_data()
{
    if(!is_Empty()) //if list is not empty
    {
        BOOK<mytype> *temp = head;   //created a copy of head
        ofstream file("database.txt", ios_base::app); //created file, to write at the end (append)
        while(temp != tail) //while list ends
        {
            file<<temp->ID<<' '<<temp->bookName<<' '<<temp->author<<' '<<temp->book_type<<' '<<temp->copies<<' '<<temp->price<<' ';  //write all info
            temp = temp->next; //move temp to next node
        }
        file<<temp->ID<<' '<<temp->bookName<<' '<<temp->author<<' '<<temp->book_type<<' '<<temp->copies<<' '<<temp->price<<' '; //for last book's info
        return true; //to confirm sucessfull writing
    }
    else //if list is empty
    {
        return false; //to confirm error in writing
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:: When I start reading, first line is read fine & stored in list, but for the next time, I can't make file to read from the next line, hence '\n'. & that creates the problem. File again reads the first line & 2nd node is created with same data.**

Loading Function:

```
void BookStoreDataBase<mytype>::load_all_data()
{
    int ID;         //variable to store ID of a book
    string bookName;//string to store name of a book
    string author;  //string to store name of author of book
    string book_type;//string to store type of a book
    long copies;    //variable to store no. of copies a book
    long price;     //variable to store price of a book
    string status;  //to store status of a book, either its in stock or not


    ifstream file("database.txt");
    while(file) //I have tried file.eof but its not working, don't know why
    {
        file>>ID>>bookName>>author>>book_type>>copies>>price>>status; //read file

        BOOK<mytype> *temp = new BOOK<mytype>(0, 0, bookName, author, book_type, copies, price);  //create a new node in memory and save all the data

        if(is_Empty()) //if list is empty, then make 1st node
        {
            head = tail = temp;
        }
        else //other wise make the next node
        {
            tail->next = temp;
            temp->prev = tail;
            tail = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

*MOREOVER*
Reading is done 1 time less than the real record. i.e. If .txt has record of 4 books, then 3 nodes are created, (& info of only 1st is repeated in every node), whereas it should read & create 4 nodes!

*I'm a beginner, any good help will be much appreciated.*

Comment: What are some of the types that you will use between <> when creating a BookStoreDataBase and a Book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you get the whole line using `std::getline()`, and then use `stringstream` class to read in everything from that into the respective variables.

Comment: Throw me the syntax. I have already tried this.
Just reads the 1st line & thats it
CODE::::::stringstream mystr;

 ifstream file("database.txt");
 while(file>>ID>>bookName>>author>>book_type>>copies>>price>>status)
 {
  
  mystr>>ID>>bookName>>author>>book_type>>copies>>price>>status;

Comment: just a suggestion @deep_ecstasy can u post the text file you're trying to read? i will give you a correct solution

Comment: OK solved.
1. I used stringstream mystr (#include<sstream>)
2. I was trying to read bookstatus in load function which was WRONG.
3. correct while condition -> while(file>>ID>>bookName>>author>>book_type>>copies>>price)
4. Into while, correct reading ->> mystr>>ID>>bookName>>author>>book_type>>copies>>price;

LOVE YOU ALOT MY DeV Bros. YOU NAILED IT. THANKYOOOOOOOOOU!

Answer (score 1):

`while (!file.eof())` is wrong, `while (file)` is wrong. Seems that every new programmer fails to understand the correct way to read from a file. I wish I knew why, it would be easier to advise newbies. The basic misunderstanding seems to be that newbies think you should test for end of file *first* and then read *second*. When really you should read first and then see if the read failed second.

This is the correct way to read from a file

```
while (file >> ID >> bookName >> author >> book_type >> copies >> price >> status)
{
}
```

Try that and see what problems still remain.

I've just noticed another problem, you try to read the status which you say is a string, but in your description of the file format there is no status. That's your real problem I think.

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup uses `while(!file.eof())`

Comment: Show the context. Using `eof` isn't illegal, it's just that most people use it wrong.

Comment: There's a big difference between this `while (!file.eof()) { file >> x; ...; }` which is what we normally see and is wrong, and this `file >> x; while (!file.eof()) { ...; file >> x; }` which is OK, although I still prefer my version above;

Comment: I have done your method, its working fine, BUTTTT it reads 1 time less. If file has 3 records. It is reading 2 books & creating 2 nodes. :( :(

Comment: Have you looked at the status issue I mentioned? If that's not it then post the contents of the file here. Hard to help without seeing what you can see.

Comment: OK solved.
1. I used stringstream mystr (#include<sstream>)
2. I was trying to read bookstatus in load function which was WRONG.
3. correct while condition -> while(file>>ID>>bookName>>author>>book_type>>copies>>price)
4. Into while, correct reading ->> mystr>>ID>>bookName>>author>>book_type>>copies>>price;

LOVE YOU ALOT MY DeV Bros. YOU NAILED IT. THANKYOOOOOOOOOU!